# File was deleted and then reappeared when folder was zipped

Tags: linux, ubuntu, zip, backtrack

I am using `Backtrack 4 Final`, which is a Linux distro that is Ubuntu based. I had a directory that contained around 5 files. I deleted one of the files, which sent it to the trash. I then zipped the directory up (now containing 4 files), using this command:

`zip -r directory.zip directory/`

When I then unzipped `directory.zip`, the file I deleted was in there again. I couldn't believe this, so I zipped up the directory again, and the file reappeared again but this time could not be opened because the operating system said it didn't exist or something. I don't remember the exact error, and I cannot make this happen again.

Would anyone happen to know why a file that was deleted from a directory would reappear in that directory after it was zipped up? Thank you.

Comment: How did you delete the file?

Comment: I right-clicked it and went to "Move to Trash"

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking it is similar to the log file where files are constantly created inside of it, and if deleted it is created again. It might not be the same exact file that ended up in your zip file. The deleted file should still be in the trash and not moved back to its original directory.